# Generating code from a uml model(activity, statechart)

Tags: android-activity, uml, modeling, diagram, generate

I need to generate java code from uml. 
I tested different modeling Tools such as modelio, eclipse modeling framework emf, visual paradigm.... 
However all of these help me to generate java code from class diagram, which will only help me in generating the getter /setter and the function header. 
I need to generate the function body from activity, statechart or sequence diagram
I need to know what is the best modeling tool to do so and can I create a code generator to be able to customize the generate code

Comment: Notoriously tricky thing. Sparx EA attempts it but you have to write code snippets. Why not just write the code?

Comment: I want to help those who does not write a code to generate one using a code generator that I will create

Comment: I downloaded entreprize architecture but I am still finding problem on how to create a code generator for my diagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Alf plugin for MagicDraw that produces UML activities, then the Lieber Lieber tool to generate code from UML activities. Executable UML is becoming a thing, finally.